# highcharts datetime type doesnt work in bootstrap 4 column

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, bootstrap-4

I work with highcharts for show datetime type chart in bootstrap 4 column like this:

HTML:

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        Right Column
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'area'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      fillOpacity: 0.1
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [{
      "x": 1592501154000,
      "y": 14520000
    }, {
      "x": 1592587554000,
      "y": 14000000
    }, {
      "x": 1592673954000,
      "y": 14800000
    }, {
      "x": 1592760354000,
      "y": 10000000
    }, {
      "x": 1592846754000,
      "y": 14000000
    }, {
      "x": 1592933154000,
      "y": 14000000
    }, {
      "x": 1593019554000,
      "y": 14000000
    }]
  }],

});
```

But in action highcharts not show true(ie: for 7 days data) result in column.

[image]

how do can i fix this problem?

Demo [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Alakian/3as0xLpb/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually... everything with a rendered chart is fine. Note that the tick interval is 2 days, so they fit perfectly for each point. By default, Highcharts doesn't render tickmark on xAxis for each point but calculated the constant timestamps - otherwise, it will disturb chart readability, for example for charts with thousands of points.

You can find in the API, that:

> In a datetime axis, the numbers are given in milliseconds, and tick marks are placed on appropriate values like full hours or days.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type

API: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes#ticks